# Doctrine many to many on same class

Tags: doctrine

I'm trying to create a social-network like feature in an app I'm building, and Want to associate a Friend with another Friend.

Assume I have this:

```
Friend:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: friend
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(75)
      notnull: true
```

How do I create a many to many relationship to associate Friend with itself?

Thanks ahead of time for your help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use self-referencing equal nest relations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/defining-models#relationships:join-table-associations:self-referencing-nest-relations:equal-nest-relations).

From the docs:

> **Equal Nest Relations**
>
> Equal nest relations are perfectly
>   suitable for expressing relations
>   where a class references to itself and
>   the columns within the reference class
>   are equal.
>
> This means that when fetching related
>   records it doesn't matter which column
>   in the reference class has the primary
>   key value of the main class.
>
> The previous clause maybe hard to
>   understand so lets take an example. We
>   define a class called User which can
>   have many friends. Notice here how we
>   use the 'equal' option.
>
> // models/User.php

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // ...

        $this->hasMany('User as Friends', array(
                'local'    => 'user1',
                'foreign'  => 'user2',
                'refClass' => 'FriendReference',
                'equal'    => true,
            )
        );
    }
}
// models/FriendReference.php
class FriendReference extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->hasColumn('user1', 'integer', null, array(
                'primary' => true
            )
        );

        $this->hasColumn('user2', 'integer', null, array(
                'primary' => true
            )
        );
    }
}
```

> Here is the same example in YAML format. You can read more about YAML in the YAML Schema > Files chapter:

```
---
# schema.yml

# ...
User:
# ...
  relations:
    # ...
    Friends:
      class: User
      local: user1
      foreign: user2
      refClass: FriendReference
      equal: true

FriendReference:
  columns:
    user1:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    user2:
      type: integer
      primary: true
```